# targeting specific app with iOS in app purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, xcode7

I have several paid apps in the iOS app store.  I would like to create a free app that will display a preview of each of the paid apps in the app store.

I have the free app completed. I have the in app portion completely. I am lost on how to target any one of my paid apps.  I only see the ability to set up Reference names and Product ID's, but how to "link" each purchase to one of my existing apps?

Comment: To clarify: do you mean you want to have buttons in App A that allow users to buy App B, App C, and App D?

Comment: Correct, that is what I would like to accomplish

Comment: What do you mean by "preview"? See [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality): _2.12 Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected. 2.13 Apps that are primarily marketing materials or advertisements will be rejected_.

Comment: @Marcus.  I have the obj c apps in the store and they are not very cheap.  I would like to create a free app that will be full of details and image, more so that what the app store allows.  This way, most all can get a better preview of what they are buying.  I realize the marketing materials statement seems to hit home, but it really does not.  My apps are about conservation and Marine life ID.  The free apps will also have a full educational and conservational value too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `SKStoreProductViewController`.

Step 1, Import StoreKit:

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
```

Step 2, conform to the `SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate` protocol.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate>
```

Step 3, show the StoreKit view controller at your convenience:

```
SKStoreProductViewController *productVC = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
productVC.delegate = self;

NSDictionary *productParameters = @{ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier: @"376558836" };
[productVC loadProductWithParameters:productParameters completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // sad face :(
    }

    if (result) {
        [self presentViewController:productVC animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}];
```

Step 4: Change 376558836 to be the app ID of the apps you want users to buy. That's one of my apps. You should buy it ;)

Step 5: Profit!

Comment: Note: just in case you try this on the iOS Simulator and hit problems: working with StoreKit on the simulator can be very problematic. You should test on a device.

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, the tutorial i used directed to SKPaymentTransactionObserver and SKProductsRequestDelegate.  I am thinking I will keep the SKPaymentTransactionObserver and associated code and replace the SKProductsRequestDelegate with the above?

Comment: a) You're talking about different things. If you use `SKStoreProductViewController` iOS does all the hard work for you – it's like embedding the App Store inside your app. b) Yes, Mancala HD is one of my apps. It's a universal purchase, so you get the Apple TV version for one low price – bargain, right? ;)

Comment: That's a different bug entirely. I suspect you have a broken connection in your storyboard – try right-clicking on the view controller in your storyboard document outline and look for any warning symbols. Note: it's definitely a different problem entirely; if my suggestion here doesn't fix it you may need to post a fresh question. For *this* question, if my answer above does what you wanted, would you be so kind as to mark it as correct so others can find it easily?

Comment: Not sure if i should ask a new question, but while all initiates properly, when i hit "cancel" on the pop screen initiated by the SKStore, the screen goes white.  I am assuming it is due to the productVC not closing, but not sure how to resolve this.